# Шифрование UDP java

Tags: java, шифрование, udp

Нужно шифровать UDP соединение c помощью TLS, JSSE вроде бы поддерживает DTLS, но я не могу найти примеров. Некоторые говорят, вообще вроде бы deprecated, поэтому может вы подскажете свежие решения этой проблемы?